# Function not covered in Jest Unit test even though the function was called in a test suite

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

I have an `<a />` tag which is used as shown below:

```
 <a class="md-color--blue-50 md-link" (click)="resetdevicesearch()" >Reset filters</a>
```

In my `ts` file , this is how the function is defined:

```
resetdevicesearch() {
    const defaultsearchvalue = {value: {name: 'Any Name/Address', id: 1}};
    this.filterdeviceinfodata = {RisClass: '', Id: '', Name: ''};
    this.deviceonlyclicked = false;
    this.initform();
    this.devicesearch = {name: 'Phone', initial: 'Phone', id: 1};
    this.deviceStatus = this.devicesearchjson.PhoneDevice.DeviceStatus.devicestatusKey;
    this.updatestatus(this.devicesearchjson.PhoneDevice.DeviceStatus.defaultKey);
    this.updatedownloadstatus();
    this.updateProtocol();
    this.devicecheckboxvalue = [];
    this.selecttdefaultcheckbox(this.devicesearchjson.PhoneDevice.Monitorfollowingattribute.monitorfollowingattributeKey);
    this.enableinputfield(defaultsearchvalue);
    this.inputchange = {name: 'Any Name/Address', id: 1, label: ''};
    // @ts-ignore
    this.filterdeviceinfodata = {RisClass: '', Id: '', Name: ''};
  }
```

Now, I am trying to write an `Unit Test` to invoke the function. This is how the test suite looks like:

```
 it('should get the anchor tag', () => {
    fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'resetdevicesearch');
      fixture.detectChanges();
      const input: ElementRef = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.md-link'));
      input.nativeElement.blur();
      tick();
      expect(page).toBeTruthy();
      expect(page.anchorTag).toBeTruthy();
      expect(component.resetdevicesearch).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  })
```

Now, the test runs succesfully , but when I check in the coverage folder, it shows `Function not covered`

[image]

Why is this happenning?

**Edit:**

Modified code:

```
 it('should get the anchor tag', () => {
    fakeAsync(() => {
      jest.spyOn(component, 'resetdevicesearch');
      fixture.detectChanges();
      const input: ElementRef = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.md-link'));
      input.nativeElement.blur();
      tick();
      expect(page).toBeTruthy();
      expect(page.anchorTag).toBeTruthy();
      expect(component.resetdevicesearch).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Jasmine, (or angular default) the `spyOn(component, 'resetdevicesearch')` mocks the function call, which does not call the underlining function. The solution is simple, replace with:

```
spyOn(component, 'resetdevicesearch').and.callThrough()
```

[an article](https://hatoum.com/blog/2016/11/12/jasmine-unit-testing-dont-forget-to-callthrough) on it for your entertainment.

However when using Jest (which is your case) [the default](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) is to call through, but you need to use it like this:

```
jest.spyOn(component, 'resetdevicesearch')
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I modified the code as you mentioned. But I its still showing `Function not covered`.

Comment: I have added the modified test suite in an edit above. Can you please have a look

Comment: would the problem be that your test calls the `blur` event while the template is linking the `click` event? could you change `blur()` to `click()` on the test?

Comment: Made the change, still the same issue :(